# Javascript immediate function invocation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am experimenting with different javascript function calls, I tried running the code below. Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/7de5vfpj/

```
var app = function () {
    var ans = {
        power: alert("power"),
        wow: alert("wow")
    }
    return ans;
}();
```

From the fiddle it alerts both "power" and "wow", when I was just expecting it to alert "wow". Why does it happen this way?

Comment: Why do you expect that? The behavior is correct. Both `alert` run as soon as the function is executed. Since it is a blocking operation, the second alert will open when the first one is closed.

Comment: It shows alerts becuase when you initialize your `power` and `wow` properties, you are initializing them with a `call` to `alert` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually immediately invoking both alerts. To get the expected behavior, you need to pass function references to the methods, not already-invoked functions (your IIFE is fine, it's your method declarations that are the cause of your problem):

```
var app = function () {
    var ans = {
        power: function() { alert("power") },
        wow: function() { alert("wow") }
    }
    return ans;
}();
```

See the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7de5vfpj/1/).

You can also, alternatively, take advantage of the fact that `Function.prototype.bind` returns a function reference:

```
var app = function () {
    var ans = {
        power: alert.bind(this, 'power'),
        wow: alert.bind(this, 'wow')
    }
    return ans;
}();

app.power();
```

Here's [that jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7de5vfpj/3/).

In your original code, if you open up your console, you'll see `Uncaught TypeError: app.power is not a function`. That's because `window.alert` returns `undefined`, and the `window.alert` functions were already invoked... therefore, they return `undefined`, and when you try to call `app.power()`, you're trying to invoke the *return value* of that method... and obviously `undefined` isn't a function, as the error very semantically states.

Answer (score 3):

Original Fiddle:

```
var app = function () {
var ans = {
    power: alert("power"),
    wow: alert("wow")
    }
  return ans;
}();

app.power();
```

The alert methods are triggered because of the object literal syntax. calling the `ans.power();` on the bottom of the fiddle is causing the following exception to be thrown.

```
Uncaught TypeError: app.power is not a function
```

the alert method does not have any return value. This is causing the `power` and `wow` properties to have `undefined` values.

This is also causing the invocation at the bottom of the fiddle to throw the exception above.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning to alert to a variable and upon initialization, this will trigger the alert.

```
var x = alert("aa"); //this will trigger alert on initialization.
```

Probably a better solution would be to make both `power` and `wow` functions.

```
var app = function () {
var ans = {
    power: function(){alert("power")},
    wow: function(){alert("wow")}
}
return ans;
}();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I created something that might be able to do what you wanted.

```
function app() {
    this.power = function(){
        alert('power');
    }
    this.wow = function(){
        alert('wow');
    }
};

var app = new app;

app.power()
app.wow()
```

you can use app.power() to call the power method, or app.wow() for the wow method. to create new methods, just follow the format of using

```
this.methodName = function(){
    //code you want to execute
}


//to call that method, outside of the function, 
//and after you set a variable to new app, call this

app.methodName();
```